# Is there a way to loosely parse JSON with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jerkson

For instance, if

```
key1:value1,key2:value2
```

is passed into the parser, I'd like it to be treated the same as:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2","value2"}
```

Comment: probably not. json REQUIREs quoted keys, proper bracketing, etc... if it's not valid json, then by definition it's NOT json.

Comment: You could write your own parser with some semantic logic... but it's not about jackson, I think.

Comment: I don't think it can be called JSON at all then

Answer (score 1):

What you have is not JSON. However, I think it might just be YAML, so check out YAML parsers if you like such a notation.